# Desktop App to UWP using Desktop App Converter

Tags: powershell, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have desktop application and want to convert it to an uwp application.
I use desktop app converter with powershell.
I am trying to convert my startup projects exe, but everytime i try execution stops at

> Running Installer in Isolated Environment
>
> VERBOSE: No installer valid exit codes specified. Using defaults: 0
>   VERBOSE: Replace any occurence of  in -InstallerArguments
>   with C:\installer\logs VERBOSE: Running installer command in isolated
>   environment: VERBOSE: Command Line =
>   "C:\installer\X.Framework.Main.exe" /passive

part. Is the exe i try to convert is wrong or -InstallerArgument i write? What should i change to end the conversion succesfully?

My PowerShell command:

> PS C:\Users\EccE\Desktop\convert> .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer
>   C:\Users\EccE\Desktop\X\X-wpf-framework\bin\Debug\X.Framework.Main.exe
>   -InstallerArguments "/passive" -Destination C:\Users\EccE\Desktop\X\X-out\ -PackageName "XApp"
>   -Publisher "CN=X" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose

Edit:

When i tried to convert project solution i got the following error:

> Running Installer in Isolated Environment
>
> VERBOSE: No installer valid exit codes specified. Using defaults: 0
>   VERBOSE: Replace any occurence of  in -InstallerArguments
>   with C:\installer\logs VERBOSE: Running installer command in isolated
>   environment: VERBOSE: Command Line =
>   "C:\installer\X.Framework.sln" /passive VERBOSE: Moving any logs
>   in
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\e931cac0-58a1-46dc-9efd-f5f442a0d814\shared\logs
>   to C:\DesktopAppConverter\e931cac0-58a1-46dc-9efd-f5f442a0d814\logs
>   VERBOSE: Cleaning up by removing isolated environment shared folder
>   'C:\DesktopAppConverter\e931cac0-58a1-46dc-9efd-f5f442a0d814\shared'
>   VERBOSE: An error occurred. Refer to logs in
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\e931cac0-58a1-46dc-9efd-f5f442a0d814\logs
>   Exception calling "RunIsolatedProcessWithMappedDirectoryAndExport"
>   with "6" argument(s): " geçerli bir Win32 uygulaması  değil. (HRESULT
>   özel durum döndürdü: 0x800700C1)" At
>   C:\Users\EccE\Desktop\convert\converter_util\Sequencer.ps1:141 char:9
>   +         $installerExitCode = [Microsoft.Centennial.Tools.DesktopAppCo ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException

Answer (score 0):

> VERBOSE: No installer valid exit codes specified

This is due to we need to package our executable program as a **installer** first, this converter can run your desktop installers through the converter in an **unattended (silent) mode** and obtain an AppX package that you can install by using the Add-AppxPackage PowerShell cmdlet on your development machine.

See the first paragraph in this document: [Desktop App Converter Preview (Project Centennial)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter)

See also the points of [Preparing your desktop app for conversion to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

***Your app installation requires user interaction.*** Your app installer must be able to run **silently**, and it must install **all of its prerequisites** that aren't on by default on a clean OS image.

You can create a MSI package and use converter to generate Appx as you want.